# Data still in database after deletion?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using sqlplus that's connected to sqldeveloper. I've added some data to my database a while ago (manually) and have just removed all of it using delete statements. The terminal confirmed the deletion by prompting "x rows deleted". Now when I go back to my database, the data still shows there, I've tried refreshing, closing and reopening and even established a new connection. Any idea why it still shows there?

Comment: "*I'm using sqlplus that's connected to sqldeveloper*" - no you are not. SQL*Plus and SQL Developer are both *client* applications to connect to an Oracle database. So "sqlplus" does not "connect to" SQL Developer.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't commit the `delete` statement other sessions won't see it. So in your SQL client (note that `sqlplus` and `SQL Developer` are both SQL *client applications*) you need to issue a `commit` after the `delete`:

```
delete from some_table;
commit;
```